# Is there a database for identifying the falling light I saw?

Tags: meteor

I witnessed a light fall from the sky. It was visibly about as bright as Mars, so brighter than meteorites I've seen, was just a point of light with no tail, and traveled much much faster than an aircraft. The horizon was blocked by a house, so I do not have any frame of reference for how far away it hit the ground (it could as well have been 3 miles or 10,000 miles away), but I do know the coordinates for where I was, and the direction is was relative to my position.

Is there some database I can use to search space events to learn what it was that I saw?

Comment: Rick rolling is so last century.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a satellite, such as the ISS, which appears as a bright, fast moving star. You can look for times when the ISS is visible on websites like http://www.heavens-above.com/

It might be a meteor (not a meteorite, that is the stone, not the streak in the sky). Meteors travel much faster than satellites. On any given night you will see several meteors each hour. A meteor that is "as bright as Mars" (which varies in brightness, and can reach -3 but is more likely to be between -1 and 0) is a less common event, but not exceptionally rare. Reports of Fireballs (those with magnitude -4 or brighter) are collected by various bodies, such as the [uk meteor network](https://ukmeteornetwork.co.uk/fireball-report/)